Фликанье текста (толщины) при фокусе на ипут
Столкнулся с проблемой: весь текст ниже инпута почему-то фликает, если брать инпут в фокус (если через девтулзы навешивать :focus, не воспроизводится).
Видео прикладываю (весь красный текст уменьшается при фокусе инпута). Сразу пишу, что font-weight нигде вообще не аффектится никакими классами.
И самое интересное, аффектится именно текст который НИЖЕ инпута, всё что выше не затрагивается.

Смотрите на красный текст ниже названия
Стэк: Tailwind, React. Ни на одном из элементов не навешаны :focus псевдоклассы, чистый css по сути, где меняется только размер текста и цвет.
Если для помощи нужны дополнительные данные, с радостью их предоставлю.
UPDATE:
Получилось углубиться в изучение и составить вот такой фрагмент кода:


<div style="background: black;">
  <p style="color: red;">Test123</p>
  <input placeholder="Введите название">
  <p style="color: red;">Test456</p>
</div>



Наглядно показывает фликинг в инпуте, который никак не связан с элементами, кажется баг хрома.
Воспроизводится только на винде, айфоны, маки, андройды - ок.

Хром 126.0.6478.185 x64, win11 - подтверждаю, меняется.

Через dev tools тоже воспроизводится - отмечай :focus-visible.

Нашёл решение. outline-width: 0px; дефолтный хромовский стиль для инпута перетирает и именно у focus-visible

А я нашёл другое решение. И вообще, outline - штука нужная.

Думаю, так срабатывает коллапс марджинов или что-то такое... Кажется, что-то такое с субпиксельным сдвигом, но за margin'ы зацепиться не получается.
Помогает contain со значением layout или paint:


body {
  background: black;
}

p {
  color: red;
}

input {
  contain: layout; /* это фикс */
}
<p>Test123</p>
<input placeholder="Введите название">
<p>Test456</p>




А как дошли до такого решения? Очень хорошо, даже не пришло в голову

@MarkKhromov, изначально стал смотреть в сторону display, overflow и contain.

Интересно как поведёт себя в браузерах помладше, посмотрел поддержку, свойство достаточно свеженькое:
https://caniuse.com/?search=contain
https://caniuse.com/?search=outline-width
Ваше решение засчитаю как верное, вы молодец, спасибо)

@MarkKhromov, подозреваю, что в старых проблемы могло и не быть. Тут явно какая-то фигня происходит... Кстати, :foccus-visible всего на пару лет старше, чем contain.

@MarkKhromov, заметь, что применение contain видимо сдвигает следующий абзац - поэтому я и думаю, что что-то с коллапсом марджинов.

Вообще интересная нативщина, конечно, не встречал ранее подобного поведения, главное преодолели. Думаю, что рано или поздно пофиксят в будущих версиях браузеров, явная бажина на уровне движка, а я подтяну свои знания в contain заодно, честно, даже и не использовал его ранее, а фича полезная очень. Спасибо)

outline-width: 0px; на focus-visible фиксит


input:focus-visible {
  outline-width: 0;
}
<div style="background: black;">
    <p style="color: red;">Test123</p>
    <input placeholder="Введите название">
    <p style="color: red;">Test456</p>
</div>




Текст фиксится, но состояние :active при клике ведёт себя странно. Плюс, outline обычно нужен, да и в целях accessability его убирать не стоит.
